# Android ImageView onclicklistenener not working

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I am new to android and I tried to implement `onclicklistener` on image view. But it's not working.. Please help. When I click on the image it dose not responds.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        ImageView ad = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ads.class));
            }
        });



        return true;

    }


}
```

this is my code...

Comment: Is your `ImageView` in your options menu layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should declare your `ImageView` in `onCreate()` as below:

> ```
>  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>     @Override
>    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>         ImageView ad = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
>       ad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ads.class));
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

Comment: that is the answer! I created the listener inside oncreatedview() :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems

First:

`startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ads.class));`

The second argument should be **an activity**

Second:

In your case, the `ImageView` and the listener should be in your `onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar issue, I got it fixed it by adding `android:layout_width="44dp"` to make sure **user would have enough area to click on**. Then, you can align image content the way you wannt. In my case:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/locationImageView"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/locationText"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/icn_edit_small_white"/>
```